# How to import the sessions list from Session Manager extension on chrome

Tags: google-chrome, session

I installed Chrome in a new computer and I cant get my list of tabs from the Session Manager extension.
There's no easy export-import option in that manager...How can I get back my list of tabs?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Google Chrome's Session Manager extension and you move to another computer, you cant easily export and import your session list.
I just found out (by trying, couldn't find the answer in google) that you can copy the contents of the folder:
..\Users\\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Storage\leveldb

into the same folder in your new computer and the list of tabs will appear the new computer's Chrome's Session Manager.

Just wanted to post this here if someone will google for it...
Maybe it's time to move to another proper extension...:)

Comment: this may copy more than necessary as I have no clue what else is contained in that folder but it works...:)